# Issue in loading a Pickled file

Tags: python

I am facing an issue when trying to load a pickled file. I received this file from somebody;I dont know the versions of the system in which the source data was pickled. Code, error & versions for my system are below.

**Code**:

```
infile = open('_test_suite.pkl','rb')

new_dict = pickle.load(infile)

infile.close()
```

**Error**:

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 1 infile = open('_test_suite.pkl','rb') ----> 2 new_dict = pickle.load(infile) 3 infile.close()
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

**Version**: Numpy 1.16.2

Pandas 0.24.2

Pickle 4.0
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

[Pip Freeze](https://drive.google.com/open?id=113B3BCqiHEvjeAbFD5qffblGlZPq1fY_)

Tried pandas.read_pickle() too. It gives a similar No module named 'core' error.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: A quick search suggests this may be the result of using the wrong version of Python (using Python 3.x when you should be using 2.x). If you add the output of `python --version` and `pip freeze` to your question, that might help determine whether or not this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks Kungphu. Added Python version and output of pip freeze to the question.

Comment: Please update your code so it can actually be run as-is (otherwise we have to make assumptions about what you've done). Reference: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am able to pickle.dump() and then pickle.load() in my system. The issue is with this specific file (_test_suite.pkl) that I received from somebody. Unfortunately, I am not supposed to share the '_test_suite.pkl' file.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the exception you're reporting would be the result of a file format issue. The only similar exceptions I'm finding are Python 2/3 mismatches. Without a working example that will let someone else reproduce your error, unfortunately, I don't think there's realistically anything we can do to help. Perhaps you could have whoever sent it produce a similar file with test data that you could share.